# Constructor async con typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promesas, puppeteer

Estoy escribiendo unas pruebas en una página de un juego para un par de pruebas automatizadas. Estoy usando puppeteer y typescript. Tengo un problema en la función `login()` pues las instrucciones que están definidas, cuando llega al login, aún no están definidas

> (node:16244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'waitFor' of undefined

Este es mi **index.ts**

```
import CorePuppeteer from './core/puppeteer.core';
import { Credentials } from './interfaces/interface';

// Parámetros
const url  = 'https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/es_ES/';
// Aquí se instancia un objeto, y el constructor se encarga de crear lo necesario para empezar a trabar
const core = new CorePuppeteer( url, false );
const credentials: Credentials = {
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    password: 'foobar'
};

// Invocación de funciones
( async () => {
    // aquí salta el error
    await core.login( credentials );
})();
```

Este es el código de **puppeteer.core.ts**

```
import puppet from 'puppeteer';
import { Credentials } from '../interfaces/interface';
export default class CorePuppeteer {

    // public browser: puppet.Browser;
    // public page: puppet.Page;
    public browser: any;
    public page: any;
    public delay = 100;

    constructor( url: string, headless = true ) {
        ( async () => {
            this.browser = await puppet.launch( { headless } );
            this.page    = await this.browser.newPage();

            await this.page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
            await this.page.goto( url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } );
        })();
    }

    
    async login( credentials: Credentials ) {
        const inputEmail = 'input[name="email"]';
        const inputPass  = 'input[name="password"]';
        const button     = 'button[type="submit"]';

        await this.page.waitFor( inputEmail );
        await this.page.type( inputEmail, credentials.email, { delay: this.delay } );
        await this.page.type( inputPass, credentials.password, { delay: this.delay } );

        await this.page.click( button );
    }
}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para esperar a que el constructor termine de setear todas las variables, antes que se invoque la siguiente función login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que un constructor no puede asíncrono por definición. Por mucho que invoques una IIFE en él mismo, la instancia se resuelve (se construye) antes de que la `Promise` de la IIFE se resuelva.
Eso da paso al error que te encuentras, y es que tienes la instancia de `CorePupeeter` **antes** y su propiedad `page` se inicializa **después**.

Como el constructor no es asíncrono, deberemos crear un método `async` que sepa resolver instancias de `CorePupeeter` de forma asíncrona, dejando el constructor privado (para evitar este error) y ese método estático.

Voy a simplificar la clase por el bien del ejemplo.

```
export default class CorePuppeteer {

    public browser: any;
    public page: any;
    public delay = 100;

    // Ahora ya no necesitamos los parámetros del constructor
    // porque sólo los usamos en el método create(...)
    // El constructor, además, será privado para NO permitir
    // crear instancias de esta clase sin usar el método create(...)
    private constructor() { }

    // El método static create(...) va a resolver instancias
    // de CorePupeeter de forma asíncrona
    static async create(url: string, headless = true): Promise<CorePuppeteer> {
        const core = new CorePuppeteer();
        core.browser = await puppet.launch( { headless } );
        core.page    = await core.browser.newPage();

        await core.page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
        await core.page.goto( url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } );

        return core;
    }

    async login( credentials: Credentials ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

El trabajo asíncrono se delega al mismo método `create` para que podamos "esperar" a que la nueva instancia de `CorePupeeter` esté lista y con todas sus propiedades inicializadas.

Lo usaríamos del siguiente modo

```
// Parámetros
const url  = 'https://lobby.ogame.gameforge.com/es_ES/';
const credentials: Credentials = {
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    password: 'foobar'
};

(async () => {
    // Esperamos la resolución
    const core = await CorePuppeteer.create(url, false);
    // En este punto, page ya está inicializado
    await core.login( credentials );
})();
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: No exactamente, las *arrow function* no tiene un contexto `this` a diferencia de las funciones definidas con la *keyword* `function`. Te dejo [este ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/onyrmLsv/) en JS (porque no sé cómo compartir un *snippet* de código con [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), jaja). Pero bueno, es aplicable igual.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué quieres decir, @Riven. Pero `this` en la IIFE del constructor hace referencia a la instancia, así que ese no era el problema del OP. En cualquier caso, esperemos que responda a ver si era lo que yo creo que era, un tema de asincronicidad... Así saldremos de dudas.

Comment: El ejemplo que te he compartido es análogo a lo que tú comentas, @Riven. No es lo mismo un contexto que un *scope*, no hay que mezclarlo. Un contexto implica siempre un *scope*, pero un *scope* no implica un contexto nuevo, como es el caso de las *arrow functions* que implican un *scope*, pero no un contexto. Eso de "functiones autoejecutables" es lo que yo estoy mencionando como [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE). Por último, los paréntesis no implican un *scope* nuevo.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon amigo mio, al parecer aquello fiable que habia visto no es correcto, pues hice una investigacion mas a profundidad en el codigo para comprobar si ambos apuntaban a la misma parte y es cierto, ambos apuntan a la instancia de la clase, por lo que no hay nuevo scope, efectivamente el probema es solo de que await no puede ser usado en el constructor y no de los scopes ni contextos, (no es que pensara que una funcion flecha tenia contexto), mas bien pense que por alguna razon la funcion flecha hacia referencia a el contexto de los parentesis el cual comprobado que no existe.

Comment: Es que al probar esto obtuve resultados muy extraños la primera vez que lo hice.